# Does MacPorts really need to install software already bundled with the OS?

Tags: macos, macports

I have noticed that often, MacPorts will install dependent software that is already embedded into my OS (OSX). Particularly, Python is a frequent example of this.

Is the MacPorts software so intelligent that it will check for native installations and install dependencies ONLY if the native installation is not compatible with the port I am trying to install?

Or, does it simply see in the list of dependencies that, "Aha, I need Python, and Python is not installed as a port, so I will install it" (even though there is a native installation of Python)?

Note: This question is meant generally, not only regarding Python. Just using that as an example.

Answer (score 1):

The package systems usually distrust the pre-installed software and install their own. It’s easier to control it, you get a more recent versions of the software and also have greater control over versioning, which helps with dependency management.

Comment: See [Macports FAQ](https://trac.macports.org/wiki/FAQ#ownlibs) for explanation of this reason.